# getRGB() result doesn't match result received from MS Paint Eyedropper

Tags: java, colors, rgb, bufferedimage

When i use getRGB() and after that get pixel color Red or Green or Blue component (it does not matter because they equal in Gray image) and compare result with MS Paint Eyedropper result, its different things.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Separator {

BufferedImage inputImg;

private int _inpupImgWidth;
private int _inpupImgHeight;                  

 public Separator(){

    try {
        inputImg = ImageIO.read(new File("inputImg.bmp"));
        _inpupImgWidth = inputImg.getWidth();
        _inpupImgHeight = inputImg.getHeight();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(getGrayPixelData(60, 44));
    try {
        ImageIO.write(inputImg, "BMP", new File("outputImg.bmp"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }

 public void getGrayPixelData(int x, int y){
     Color myColor = new Color(inputImg.getRGB(x, y));       
     System.out.println("Red: " + myColor.getRed());
     System.out.println("Green: " + myColor.getGreen());
     System.out.println("Blue: " + myColor.getBlue());
     }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Separator();
    System.out.println("The End");
}
}
```

here is the link of image i use http://postimage.org/image/t6tvlv941/

Comment: *"here is the link of image i use"* Can you reproduce this effect in an image under 20Kb (as opposed to one that is over 500Kb)?

Answer (score 0):

The image is in greyscale mode.

How you convert a greyscale value into R, G, B is quite arbitrary.

A naive way would be to assign an identical greyscale value to each of the R, G and B components.

A more sophisticated way would be to use some transformation that takes into account the eye's sensitivity to these different components, or which takes account of the profile of your monitor or other display device.

So clearly, Java and your program are using different transformations. But in either case, the precise R, G and B values are essentially meaningless: the original data is not in R, G, B format.

Comment: On every other image i get identical results for RGB in Paint and in my program. The problem occurs only with this certain picture. Can you please explain that?

Comment: Without at least seeing the other images and possibly seeing the conversion algorithm used by MS Paint, I can't explain the precise details. But you seem to be inventing a "problem" that doesn't exist: there is no intrinsic necessity for MS Paint to convert greyscale values to RGB in precisely the same way as Java or any other program or library.